# cant understand how this view in SQL works

Tags: sql, database

I am having a hard time understand how the create view, TRANSCRIPTVIEW, manages to set the grade of 0 for those who did not take a course. An explanation would help, the solution and question is below. Thanks.

Student(Id,Name)
Transcript(StudId,CourseName,Semester,Grade)

Formulate the following query in SQL: 
Create a list of all students (Id, Name) and, for each student, list the average grade for the courses taken in the S2002 semester.
Note that there can be students who did not take any courses in S2002. For these, the average grade should be listed as 0.
Solution:
We first create a view which augments TRANSCRIPT with rows that enroll every student into a NULL course with the grade of 0. Therefore, students who did not take anything in semester ’S2002’ will have the average grade of 0 for that semester.

Below is what confuses me, how does this work and why does it work?

```
CREATE VIEW TRANSCRIPTVIEW AS (

( SELECT * FROM Transcipt)
UNION
( 
SELECT S.Id,NULL,’S2002’,0
FROM Student S)
WHERE S.Id NOT IN ( 
SELECT T.StudId
FROM Transcript T
WHERE T.Semester = ’S2002’) )
)

Remaining solution:
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, AVG(T.Grade)
FROM Student S, TRANSCRIPTVIEW T
WHERE S.Id = T.StudId AND T.Semester = ’S2002’ GROUP BY S.Id
```

Comment: Table transcript must contain 4 fields.  If someone were to add a 5th this would break.   The first select is getting all transcripts.  The second select is getting all students who don't have a record in transcript for semester S2002 and assigning them a 4th column value of 0 and a course name of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how the create view, TRANSCRIPTVIEW, manages to set the grade of 0 for those who did not take a course`

The set of students who did not take a course in semester S2002 have no record in the transcript table for that semester. Those who did take a course in that semester do have a record in the table for that semester. The query supplies values `NULL, 'S2002',0` for students if they are not in the Transcript table for semester S2002:

```
  SELECT S.Id,NULL,’S2002’,0 FROM Student S)    -- this parenthesis is wrong
  -- this following where conditions looks for students NOT IN the 2002 subset:
  WHERE S.Id NOT IN
   -- this next part gets a list of studentids for semester 2002
   (  
   SELECT T.StudId FROM Transcript T
    WHERE T.Semester = ’S2002’
   )
```

Comment: I still don't understand how it searches the entire database for it, I don't see a loop.

Comment: Execute this query: `select s.id, 'dog' as favoriteanimal from Student S`

Comment: Select returns a SET. There's no need for a loop. SQL is non-procedural. The select is issued against Student table and EVERY student who does not exist in Transcript for 2002 is returned by that select;  those supplied values are supplied for each row returned by the select.

Comment: I guess the last question I have before I mark this as the right answer is how does the Select statement, the first one where it says Null, then S2002, set that value for those who are not in S2012. Coming from a Java background I don't see how this makes sense. So I do SELECT on ID, and I am fine so far, then there is a comma followed by a NULL, even though the student table does not have that many parameters to begin with, it has 2 parameters. A step by step break down would greatly help.

Comment: Execute this statement: `select s.id, 'dog' as animal, 'vanilla' as flavor, 'steel' as metal, 'rose' as flower, 'mouse' as rodent from Student as S`. That means, for each row in the set of rows returned by the SELECT ... from STUDENT statement, give me the id and these values I am supplying.

Comment: Then execute that same statement, appending the following WHERE-CONDITION, which will EXCLUDE from the previous set those rows whose student ID is among those in the in-list:  `WHERE S.id NOT IN (1,3,5,7,9)`  Substitute  for 1,3,5,7,9 some actual id values you know to exist.  The statement reads 'select <somecolumns> from Students ... where student.id NOT IN ( select some student ids from Transcript for a particular semester)`

Comment: Caveat: when two sets are UNIONed, they must have the same number of columns and the datatypes of the columns in the sets must be the same. So the arbitrary list of character-type columns I provided (dog, vanilla, steel, rose, mouse) could not be unioned to a set with fewer or more columns or to a set that had some dates, floats, or integers in it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in your qusetion is ridiculous.  The better solution is:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, AVG(case when  T.Semester = ’S2002’ then T.Grade end) as AvgS2002Grade
FROM Student S left outer join
     TRANSCRIPTVIEW T
     on S.Id = T.StudId AND T.Semester = ’S2002’
GROUP BY S.Id
```

The query in your question is overly complicated.  It is using a `union` (which should really be `union all` for performance reasons) to be sure all students are included.  Gosh, this is what `left outer join` is for.  It is doing filtering in the `where` clause, when a conditional aggregation is more suitable.  It uses archaic join syntax, instead of the ANSI standard.

I hope you are not learning SQL with those shortcomings.

Comment: this was in my book :(. Please recommend me some good sources to learn SQL more efficiently

Comment: @Richard Mckenna - this forum is the best source. Besides, you did not specify which version of SQL.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff how do you handle the scenario where students haven't taken courses in S2002, also, ANSI SQL is what I want to learn, preferably the latest version. This forum doesn't have a standard curricula to teach you SQL. Please help